# Getting Inconsistantcy Error When Using Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

When I click on the viewController posted below, I get an error saying:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Routine isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c05320'

Can anyone help me make this work?

Here is my code:

```
@implementation RoutineTableViewController

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize eventsArray;
@synthesize entered;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.eventsArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.tableView setEditing: !self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.tableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [eventsArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Add an event

-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [eventsArray insertObject:routine atIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];
    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
        if(eventsArray && entered)
        {
            [eventsArray addObject:entered];
            [tableView reloadData];
            [self addEvent];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [eventsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Dequeue or create a new cell.

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         // Delete the managed object at the given index path.
         NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];

         // Update the array and table view.
         [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

         // Commit the change.
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Handle the error.
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you are using a `Routine` object where you should be using an NSString. Without more information on where exactly in the huge code dump the exception is being thrown from I can only guess, but this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` looks particularly suspicious:

```
Routine *routine = (Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [self.eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If the value from the array is really a `Routine`, the assignment of that object to a label's `text` property is most likely wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is where the error is coming from.  How can I fix this?  It is supposed to be the text from the name attribute of the entity called Routine.

Comment: Then assign `[routine name]` to the `text` property. But do watch out, as near as I can tell you have inserted both `Routine` objects and NSStrings into eventsArray. You should probably restructure your code to not be doing that, or if absolutely necessary you could use `isKindOfClass:` to know whether any particular object is a Routine (meaning you need to call `[routine name]` to get a string) or an NSString.

Comment: Thanks Anomie. Ok so there is no reason for me to have `Routine` objects and NSStrings in eventsArray.  I believe eventsArray should only have the fetched data that will be presented in the table view, correct?  How can I restructure my code to do this?

Comment: @Faisal: Why do you think that?

Comment: You said I was inserting both Routine objects and NSStrings into eventsArray.  I think it should be just for nsstrings right?  I'm not sure how to fix this exactly.  This is my first time adding Core Data to an app

Comment: Now, the table loads fine when i click its tab bar item, but when i enter a text and press ok to save it, i get the error "2011-04-07 00:02:22.171 Curl[15940:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d24500'" at the line `cell.textLabel.text = [routine name];`

Comment: @Faisal: It has nothing really to do with core data. If the eventsArray shouldn't contain Routine objects, just don't add Routine objects to it. Your new error is the same thing I cautioned you about 11 hours ago: now you're trying to call the `name` method on an NSString thinking it is a Routine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for being patient with me.  I'm still trying to get a hand of this core data stuff.  How can I make it reflect the model I want?  I want the user to create a list of cells, the name of each cell should be the name attribute of the routine object.  I think their should be one routine object that has a bunch of name attributes, is that correct?

Comment: "one routine object that has a bunch of name attributes" doesn't make any sense. What you should do to fix your error is stop inserting NSStrings into `eventsArray` in your `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:` method.

Comment: Thanks Anomie, i'm going to fix that code right now.  Regarding the name attributes, what I want is an empty table the first time the app is launched until the user inputs strings which correspond to these cells.  Then the cells will be clickable and will yield a sub table view.

Comment: unforetuneately i don't think editing the alertview:willdissmiss code will fix the problem as I think I need that code there to reload the table, dont I?